# Policy Ignores b2c Authentication scheme

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-3.0

I added a costum Policy to my .net core 3.0 API and it breaks the default B2C Authentication scheme and I have no clue why..

I used documentation from microsoft itself found here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.0

AuthenticationScheme looks as followed:

```
           services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                });
```

Following code that creates the policy

```
         var groupOptions = new List<GroupOptions>();
            configuration.Bind("Groups", groupOptions);

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                foreach (var groupOption in groupOptions)
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(
                        groupOption.GroupName,
                        policy =>
                        {
                            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme);
                            //policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme);
                            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                            //policy.Requirements.Add(new IsMemberOfGroupRequirement(groupOption.GroupName, groupOption.GroupId));
                            policy.AddRequirements(new IsMemberOfGroupRequirement(groupOption.GroupName, groupOption.GroupId));
                        });
                }

            }).AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, IsMemberOfGroupHandler>();
```

And the policy itself

```
    public class IsMemberOfGroupRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public readonly string GroupId;
        public readonly string GroupName;

        public IsMemberOfGroupRequirement(string groupName, string groupId)
        {
            GroupName = groupName;
            GroupId = groupId;
        }
    }

    public class IsMemberOfGroupHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsMemberOfGroupRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IMicrosoftGraphConnector _microsoftGraphConnector;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public IsMemberOfGroupHandler(IMicrosoftGraphConnector microsoftGraphConnector, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _microsoftGraphConnector = microsoftGraphConnector;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
            AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsMemberOfGroupRequirement requirement)
        {
            var id = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == Constants.Claims.Id);

            if (await CheckGroup(id, requirement))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }

        protected async Task<bool> CheckGroup(System.Security.Claims.Claim id, IsMemberOfGroupRequirement requirement)
        {

            var microsoftGraphGroup = await _microsoftGraphConnector.GetMicrosoftGraphServiceClient()
                .Users[id.Value].MemberOf
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();

            var groupDTO = _mapper.Map<ICollection<GroupDTO>>(microsoftGraphGroup);

            foreach (var group in groupDTO)
            {
                if (group.Id.Equals(requirement.GroupId))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to detail your observation - what does “break” mean?

Comment: While breaks means it completely ignores the scheme set for authentication. But as you can see in the code the scheme is added in the policy